# run c program using php

Tags: php, c

how to run c program using php `exec()`
i have seen many results from google search 
it is possible by exec() function
but i am  unable to use it
i tried in this way
i wrote a program in c

```
**myc.c**
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("Hello, world\n");

    return 0;
}

**test.php**
<?php
exec('myc.c');
?>
```

can any one help me pls in this regard
i executed this through wamp server by placing in www folder

Comment: c is a programming language so you need to compile before executing..where php is scripting language so you can execute directly...

Comment: You're trying to run you C source code. Good luck...

Answer (score 9):

If you want to run a program written in C then you have to run the *program* and not the source code.

Compile your C into an executable, then call the name of the executable from `exec`.

Answer (score 9):

C Program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if(argv[1])
    printf("First arg %d\n", argv[1]);
    if(argv[2])
    printf("Second arg %d", argv[2]);
    return 0;
}
```

---

PHP Code

```
<?php
exec("testone.exe 125 70", $out);
print_r($out);
?>
```

---

Combined Output:

```
<!-- Array ( [0] => First arg 27 [1] => Second arg 27 ) -->
```

Answer (score 8):

You should compile your C program and then execute it with PHP.
PHP will not run your C code, even though they have similar syntaxes.

The PHP `exec` function will execute a command similar to how it is done in a shell or command prompt.

Comment: You could `exec gcc -o myc myc.c` and then `exec ./myc` but then you will be at serious risk of ending up on [the daily wtf](http://thedailywtf.com/) :P

Comment: pls explain the process detail

Answer (score 7):

Today's PHP ecosystem provides a couple better solutions for this now.

### 1. Write a PHP extension

You can use [Zephir](https://zephir-lang.com/en) to easily build PHP extensions in a PHP-like language. They provide a mechanism called [custom optimizers](https://docs.zephir-lang.com/0.11/en/optimizers) that cleanly binds arbitrary C libraries or custom C code to your extension.

While it requires a little more work, it *could* (YMMV) result in near-C performance via native PHP calls, and upgrades your PHP-fu. You also might accidentally fall in love with Phalcon.

In my personal experience, pure Zephir actually harmed the performance of pure PHP for my task, so I would recommend it only if you want to leverage the power of existing C libs, or you have heavy workloads.

[This Github comment](https://github.com/phalcon/zephir/pull/21#issuecomment-26178522) provides a brief overview of why you should use the Zephir optimizer over an inline [CBLOCK](https://github.com/phalcon/zephir/blob/c893389cc6de6fc6a52199ae401aa91ff7eb1206/test/cblock.zep#L13) and how to structure your directories/files.

### 2. Use FFI

As of PHP 7.4, the [Foreign Function Interface](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ffi.examples-basic.php) comes built-in. You can also [install it](https://github.com/dstogov/php-ffi#install) as an extension for older versions of PHP.

The upside? You don't have to write your own PHP extension to use C code. The downside? Right now FFI performance doesn't really compare to actual C code. You can think of it more like a crutch than a batmobile.

If you care about high performance, try option 1.